# Shifting div while hovered

Tags: html, css, scale, absolute

I wanted to make an image with overlay layer that changes size when it's hovered, but when I'm hovering the overlay layer is shifted to the right and bottom.

I think it is because of this part, but I have no idea what else I could use.

```
top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```css
.panel-daredevil img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.panel-daredevil {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-daredevil .text {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.panel-daredevil .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 238);
  border-radius: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.panel-daredevil:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.panel-daredevil:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="panel-daredevil">
    <a href="daredevil.html">
      <img src="pictures/daredevil.jpg" alt="daredevil">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="text">daredevil</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your hover transform completely overwrites the static rule. See the linked duplicate for proper syntax. You'll need to _include_ the original transform in the hover transform.

Comment: I think it's because the parent div (panel-daredevil) does not have the expected dimensions. The overlay is placed in the center of the parent div (thanks to the absolute position, and the top, left and transform styles). However, you don't control the dimensions of this div. I suggest you add width and height styles to this div as well. And as @isherwood said, you overwrite transform in the hover rule. Thus, you don't have the translate(-50%, -50%) applied so your overlay moves to the bottom right.